# The use of setFocusable in java

Tags: java, swing, focus

I have created class start, where on pressing the Right Arrow key, a rectangle block will move. But this code only works when adding `setFocusable(true)`. I read the Java Doc,and many previous Stack Overflow questions, but I still have no idea why `setFocusable` is so important. Please answer me explaining this code only.

```
public class start extends JPanel{

    int x=0, xa=1;

    public start() {

        addKeyListener(new KeyListener(){

            public void keyPressed(KeyEvent ke){

                if(ke.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT){

                    xa=xa+1;

                    repaint();

                }
            }

            public void keyTyped(KeyEvent ke){}

            public void keyReleased(KeyEvent ke){}

        });

        setFocusable(true);

    }

    public void paint(Graphics g){

        super.paint(g);

        g.fillRect(x+xa,100,40,50);

    }

}
```

Comment: Instead of `KeyListener` use [key bindings](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html#howto)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but still i am asking about setFocusable

Answer (score 2):

> but I still have no idea why setFocusable is so important.

Events are only dispatched to the component that has focus. So your KeyEvent will only be dispatched to the panel if it is "focusable" and it has focus.

See [Motion Using the Keyboard](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2013/06/09/motion-using-the-keyboard/) for more information about this topic including two different solutions.

Answer (score 1):

When a Frame/Window is shown, by default, the `FocusTraversalPolicy` default component is given focus. The `DefaultFocusTraversalPolicy` accpets a component if it is focusable and `isFocusTraversableOverridden` is true or if its `peer` is focusable.

When `setFocusable(true)` is called, the flag `isFocusTraversableOverridden` is set to `FOCUS_TRAVERSABLE_SET`, so this elects a `component` to be chosen by the `DefaultFocusTraversalPolicy` as the default component. So, even if a `JPanel` is by default focusable, the explicit call makes it be selected as the default component to gain the focus.

Anyway, this is not the correct way to requestFocus to a `Component`. You should try `requestFocus` or `requestFocusInWindow` once the `Component` is made visible.

Also, consider overriding `paintComponent` instead of `paint`.

Comment: Can you be less technical ??

Comment: When a Frame is shown, it relies on a policy to give focus to the default component. The default implementaion of this policy selects the first component which is focusable and isFocusTraversableOverridden is true. When you call setFocusable(), isFocusTraversableOverridden is set to true, so this enables the component to gain focus once the Frame is displayed. Just remember this is not the way to set the focus to a component. Dunno if its any clearer, hope so.

Comment: Please, also refer to the javadoc http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/DefaultFocusTraversalPolicy.html

Answer (score 0):

The `focusable` flag indicates whether a component can gain focus or not. The `JPanel` component is focusable by default, so there will be no change when you set it to `true`. Also the `setFocusable` does not set the focus in itself.

Comment: That's what i'm asking.When i am trying to move the rectangle block without setFocusable(true) included,it is showing no check... I mean this code is not working without `setFocusable(true)`

Answer (score 0):

Focus is so important because keyboard and mouse wheel events (for example) get sent to the focus owner.

http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/focus.html