# How to make the KeyListener functional?

Tags: java, swing, awt, keylistener

I am learning java, and trying to create a little pong game just as a little test for me, but I can't make the keys right/left arrows work in my code, and I followed some tutorials but still not working.

My enemy and ball from de game works just fine, everything has collision, but still I can't make the controls/keys work.

Here is the code I'm using and my class Player (I think the mistake is somewhere here but I still don't know how to find it).

**Code**

```
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {    
        if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT)
            player.right = true;        
        
            else if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT)
                player.left = true;
    }

    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT)
            player.right = false;
        
            else if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT)
                player.left = false;
    }
```

**Class "Player"**

```
public class Player {

    public boolean right,left;
    public int x,y;
    public int width,height;
    
    public Player(int x, int y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.width = 40;
        this.height = 10;
    }
    
    public void tick() {
        if(right) {
            x++;
        }
        else if(left) {
            x--;
        }
        if(x+width > Game.WIDTH) {
            x = Game.WIDTH - width;
        }
        else if(x < 0) {
            x = 0;
        }
    }

    public void Render(Graphics g) {
        g.setColor(Color.blue);
        g.fillRect(x, y, width,height);
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you using registering your key event listener?

Comment: _I followed some tutorials_ Did you follow this [tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/) ?

Comment: *"(I think the mistake is somewhere here but I still don't know how to find it)"* That is ***one*** of the reasons we urge people to post a [mre]. By definition, the problem will be *somewhere* in the MRE. Don't post random code snippets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This small example has a `KeyListener` that works. The player doesn't move, because the `Player.tick` method is not called.

```
// Pong.java

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.WindowConstants;

public class Pong {
    public static void main(String[] arguments) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> new Pong().createAndLaunchGui());
    }

    private void createAndLaunchGui() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Pong");
        frame.setBounds(240, 160, Game.WIDTH, Game.HEIGHT);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setContentPane(new Game());
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}


// Game.java

import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Game extends JPanel {
    public static int WIDTH = 800;
    public static int HEIGHT = 600;

    private final Player player = new Player(400, 300);

    public Game() {
        setFocusable(true);

        addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void keyPressed(KeyEvent keyEvent) {
                System.out.println("Game.keyPressed -- event: " + keyEvent);

                if (keyEvent.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) {
                    player.right = true;
                } else if (keyEvent.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) {
                    player.left = true;
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void keyReleased(KeyEvent keyEvent) {
                System.out.println("Game.keyReleased -- event: " + keyEvent);

                player.right = false;
                player.left = false;
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics graphics) {
        super.paintComponent(graphics);

        player.render(graphics);
    }
}
```

The key to solving your problem might be the call to the `setFocusable(true)` method in the constructor of the `Game` class. As explained in this [Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29753536), events are only dispatched to the component that has focus. See that answer for more details and a link to a blog post with an extensive explanation.